# Extracting cells from one column when conditions match in other columns in a Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file I load into a data frame.

... SCity, DCity, CVtype, L1Name....

I want to extract L1Name for specific combinations of SCity, DCity and CVType.

Ideally the data should return as a list so that I can use each return value to extract other information from the Dataframes, like cost of each L1Name for other (non-matching) values of SCity, DCity and CVType.

Example SCity is 'Chennai', Dcity is 'Pune', Type is '32 Ft' I should get a list of L1Name
f1
f2
f3

I don't understand how to search on multiple columns

> cimsBid[cimsBid['CVtype']=='32 FT'].groupby('L1Name').nunique()

gives me a Pivot of the data on all the L1 Names.

> cimsBid[cimsBid['CVtype']=='32 FT',cimsBid['SCity']=='Chennai'].groupby('L1Name').nunique()

gave me the following error message:

> Name: SCity, Length: 22001, dtype: bool)' is an invalid key

The expected output is:{'f1','f2'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `()` and chained condition by `&` or `|`:

```
#filter by & for bitwise AND
df = cimsBid[(cimsBid['CVtype']=='32 FT') & (cimsBid['SCity']=='Chennai')]

#filter by | for bitwise OR
#df = cimsBid[(cimsBid['CVtype']=='32 FT') | (cimsBid['SCity']=='Chennai')]

out = df.groupby('L1Name').nunique()
```

Comment: Thanks!  How do I get the output as a list of L1Name rather than the pivot table size print?

Comment: @user2338557 Do you need `cimsBid. loc[(cimsBid['CVtype']=='32 FT') & (cimsBid['SCity']=='Chennai'), 'L1Name']. unique(). tolist()`?

Comment: That works too!  I tried to combine grouping without realising the output of a group by is NOT dataframe, it is a iterable GroupBy object